# Is there a way for a receiving contract to respond to ERC20's being sent to it w/ safeTransfer?

Tags: solidity, erc-20

I need my contract to know when both ERC721's and ERC20's are sent in outside of a function call. For ERC721's safeTransferFrom, I put this logic in the codeblock of onERC721Received by having it add data to state before giving a return. Could I do the same with ERC20's safeTransfer helper?

From what I understand, I can't treat incoming safe ERC20's as a listener the same way I can with ERC721's and safeTransfer is just to help the calling contract to safely transfer the token. Just confirming